# Draw Route on google Map in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to draw route on mapview using latitude and longitude. how is it possible to draw?

Here is my code. but it is not working. i have added location in points Mutable array. and after that called drawRoute function to draw route between that location.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = (double) 23.00000;
    location.longitude = (double) 73.00000;


CLLocationCoordinate2D location2;
    location2.latitude = (double) 73.00000;
    location2.longitude = (double) 23.00000;

    CLLocation *locationPoint1 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location.latitude longitude:location.longitude];
    CLLocation *locationPoint2 = [[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:location2.latitude longitude:location2.longitude]; 
    [self.points addObject:locationPoint1];
    [self.points addObject:locationPoint2];
[self performSelector:@selector(drowRoute)];
}


-(void)drowRoute{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
 //   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor blueColor]CGColor]);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    for(int idx = 0; idx < self.points.count; idx++)
    {
        CLLocation* location = [self.points objectAtIndex:idx];
        CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:self.view];

        if(idx == 0)
        {
            // move to the first point
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
        }
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use it using Goggle Map Services. You just have to pass longitude and latitude as a parameter to `URL` and rest is taken care by Google maps.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  locationManager.delegate = self;
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters; 
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",c_lat,c_long,lat,lat];
  //saddr= we pass source address long, lat.
  //daddr= we pass destination address long, lat.

  //--------use this if you have current long,lat and destination's address or street name etc...

   NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@",
                currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude,
                [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]]; // this line will open Google map on Maps application on device and in Safari in Simulator.


}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

  curntloc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

 NSLog(@"in func--> %f %f",curntloc.coordinate.latitude, curntloc.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example source code for drawing route on the map using lat,long coordinates.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

This is how i learnt to do the very task.

Besides, to draw lines, in [this post](http://navarra.ca/?p=786) you will find classes for annotation. Check out the source code in the post, it will be more then sufficient to help you i hope.

By using the classes in the second link i have post, you will just have to provide the coordinates (lat,long) and the classes will do the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
    [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
                                options:NSLiteralSearch
                                  range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
    NSInteger len = [encoded length];
    NSInteger index = 0;
    NSMutableArray *array = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSInteger lat=0;
    NSInteger lng=0;
    while (index < len) {
        NSInteger b;
        NSInteger shift = 0;
        NSInteger result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;
        NSNumber *latitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] autorelease];
        NSNumber *longitude = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] autorelease];
        CLLocation *loc = [[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] autorelease];
        [array addObject:loc];
    }

    return array;
}
-(NSArray*) calculateRoutesFrom:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) f to: (CLLocationCoordinate2D) t {
    NSString* saddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", f.latitude, f.longitude];
    NSString* daddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", t.latitude, t.longitude];

    NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=%@&daddr=%@", saddr, daddr];
    NSURL* apiUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:apiUrlStr];

    NSString *apiResponse = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:apiUrl];
    NSString* encodedPoints = [apiResponse stringByMatching:@"points:\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"" capture:1L];

    return [self decodePolyLine:[encodedPoints mutableCopy]];
}
-(void) centerMap {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90;
    CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180;
    CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90;
    CLLocationDegrees minLon = 180;
    for(int idx = 0; idx < routes.count; idx++)
    {
        CLLocation* currentLocation = [routes objectAtIndex:idx];
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
            maxLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude < minLat)
            minLat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
            maxLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        if(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude < minLon)
            minLon = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    }
    region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
    region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
    region.span.latitudeDelta  = maxLat - minLat;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = maxLon - minLon;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
-(void) calculate_distance{
    float target = [location1 distanceFromLocation:location2]/1000;
    text2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%fkm",target];
    routes = [[self calculateRoutesFrom:location1.coordinate to:location2.coordinate] retain];

    if([routes count]!=0){
        [self updateRouteView];
        [self centerMap];
        UIAlertView* alert1=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE" message:text2 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert1 show];
        [alert1 release];
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"MESSAGE" message:@"We could not draw direction between your desired locations" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    location1=0;
    location2=0;
}
-(void) updateRouteView {
    CGContextRef context =  CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 
                                                  routeView.frame.size.width, 
                                                  routeView.frame.size.height, 
                                                  8, 
                                                  4 * routeView.frame.size.width,
                                                  CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                                  kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);

    for(int i = 0; i < routes.count; i++) {
        CLLocation* location = [routes objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint point = [mapView convertCoordinate:location.coordinate toPointToView:routeView];

        if(i == 0) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, point.x, routeView.frame.size.height - point.y);
        } else {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, routeView.frame.size.height - point.y);
        }
    }

    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];

    routeView.image = img;
    CGContextRelease(context);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the code given below to draw a route between two locations:

```
- (void)fetchPolylineWithOrigin:(CLLocation *)origin destination:(CLLocation *)destination {
    NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", origin.coordinate.latitude, origin.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", destination.coordinate.latitude, destination.coordinate.longitude];
    NSString *directionsAPI = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    NSString *directionsUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving", directionsAPI, originString, destinationString];
    NSURL *directionsUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:directionsUrlString];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *fetchDirectionsTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:directionsUrl completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         if(error) {
             //Error in fetching poline
             return;
         }

         NSArray *routesArray = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

         if ([routesArray count] > 0) {
             NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
             NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
             NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
             GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
             [self drawPath:path];
         }
     }];
    [fetchDirectionsTask resume];
}


- (void)drawPath:(GMSPath *)newPath {

    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:newPath];
    polyline.strokeColor =PathColor;
    polyline.strokeWidth = 2.5;
    polyline.geodesic = YES;

    NSArray *styles = @[[GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:PathColor],
                        [GMSStrokeStyle solidColor:PathColor]];
    NSArray *lengths = @[@100000, @50000];
    polyline.spans = GMSStyleSpans(polyline.path, styles, lengths, kGMSLengthRhumb);
    polyline.map = _mapView;

}
```